# hibernate.cfg.xml mapping resources

Tags: hibernate, maven

Is there any way to use a regular expression (or just *) to tell Hibernate to pick up all of the hbm.xml files in a given directory, or even in the project?  I just reverse engineered my database, and don't feel like specifying a hundred plus tables with <mapping resource="...">

I'm using Maven to run hbm2java.  Do I need to indicate something in my component configuration?

My hibernate.cfg.xml currently looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@....</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">hithere</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">shhhh</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">foobar</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>

        <mapping resource="com/foo/bar/db/Blip.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="com/foo/bar/db/Blap.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="com/foo/bar/db/Blop.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `hibernate.cfg.xml` supports regular expression to selectively import resource. You can resort to import the resource pragmatically .Before calling [buildSessionFactory()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#buildSessionFactory%28%29) of [Configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html) to build the [SessionFactory](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html) , use regular expression to find out a list of the mapping file path that you want to hibernate to pick up , then use [addResource()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#addResource%28java.lang.String%29) or [addClass()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#addClass%28java.lang.Class%29) to add them to the [Configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html) object.

Or if you use JPA with hibernate as the implementation, you can enable auto discovery of all hbm.xml files by setting the property `hibernate.archive.autodetection` to `hbm` (See [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/configuration.html#setup-configuration-bootstrapping))

Comment: That is a very useful answer, but alas, I was wanting to include the resources for purposes of running hbm2java on them (I didn't know enough to point that out in the question!)  And you confirmed what I thought about the possible use of regular expressions.  So it doesn't help me directly.  But I'm sure others will get use from it.

Comment: I think you're right that hibernate.cfg.xml simply doesn't support this.  And after a time, it turns out that loading up the file with the entire list of hbm.xml files, while tedious, was a one time thing and I haven't had to mess with it since.  In the end, not that big of a deal.  Thanks for your help!